# Stuck in System is running on low-graphic mode

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal

On ubuntu 16.04 I accidentally deleted usr/share/X11/xorg.conf directory, now the OS totally freeze after booting (system is running liw-graphic mode) and I can’t use the terminal (ctrl alt f*) even in x safe mode :D

Answer (score 2):

Try to boot in recovery mode from GRUB - press <kbd>Shift</kbd> on boot and select corresponding line in GRUB.

Login to the system and do the following actions:

1. find all packages, which have files in xrod.conf.d

   ```
   dpkg -S usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
   ```
2. then reinstall the packages manually (see your output from command above)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core
   ```

Comment: Thanks for replying but again I can't login to the system, I get system is running in low-graphics mode screen

Comment: The answer says *Try to boot in **recovery mode** from GRUB - press Shift on boot and select corresponding line in GRUB.* If you don't understand then say so, ask for clarification.

Comment: @MichaelBay I meant the issue happens recovery mode too. I found that I can't access the terminal because the keyboard isn't recognized at all, however, I managed to access the Harddrive from another PC and put back the deleted directory and everything works fine now.